Failure updating ValidationRule using Tooling API
I'm trying to disable a validation rule using the Tooling API, I was able to update custom fields using the API and assumed this will follow the same method, but something is wrong and I'm not sure if it's blocked somehow or if I'm missing something in the payload.
I am sending this payload:
{
  "Metadata": {
    "errorConditionFormula": "AND(\n    IsClosed__c = false,\n    IsResolved__c = true\n)",
    "errorDisplayField": "IsResolved__c",
    "errorMessage": "Is Resolved cannot be set to true unless Is Closed is true",
    "active": false
  },
  "FullName": "Xyz__c.Abc_Def",
}

To this URL:
PATCH /services/data/v62.0/tooling/sobjects/ValidationRule/03d...QAG

And I'm getting:
[
  {
    "message": "In field: fullName - no ValidationRule named Xyz__c.Abc_Def found",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY",
    "fields": []
  }
]

I tried playing with the payload, but it's clearly guiding me to only include FullName and Metadata (which was the case for CustomField as well), I dropped any null metadata values, and I'm stuck.
Any suggestions for tackling this?
Thanks ahead

Is the custom object part of a managed package?

It says "ManageableState": "installedEditable", so I assumed the editable means it's ok to deactivate. I might be wrong though, I couldn't find any documentation on this.

@ZvikaT Once this package is upgraded, it'll override your changes.

I'm not concerned about change overrides when upgrading, my use case is the need to update validation rules (de-activate them), perform some actions and then revert the validation rules changes right after. The problem is it doesn't let me deactivate the rules.

If the validation rule is included in a managed package, you must prefix the namespace in the FullName, i.e. MyNamespace__CustomObject__c.MyNamespace__ValidationName. You could also run a GET against that VR to see the valid FullName

Just to confirm, I can rely on the the FullName value appearing in the GET response, and will not need under any circumstance to parse, manually adjust, add namespace values or anything else?

Yes, the one in the GET response is always the right one.
